# Calculate the percentage of sum of hash values

Tags: ruby

Please review my code and help on How can I make it better calculation in method and class definition with SOLID ruby principles??

The application has a static JSON file which contains:

```
{
  "homes": {
    "person_a": "windows+tables",
    "person_b": "lights+tables",
    "person_c": "doors+curtains"
 }
}
```

The application should, for each user request, calculate quotes for the 3 insurers. The business requirement is as follows:

The quote is a 10% of the rate if 2 covers are matched or 20% if just 1 cover is matched and that is the biggest requested, 25% if it is the second biggest or 30% if is the third.

the request from user is as follow

```
{:curtains=>20, :tables=>30, :windows=>50}
```

The system should not return a quote if the value is zero(0)

For eg: the application will return  the result for the above user request

```
{
    person_a: 8 (10% of 80 (two matches on windows and tables))
    person_b: 7.5 (25% of 30 (one match on tables, the 2nd biggest cover))
    insurer_c: 6 (30% of 20 (one match on curtains, the 3rd biggest cover)

}
```

This is my solution:

`````
require_relative './rules'

module Coverage
  class CalculateQuotes
    def initialize(quotes)
      @quotes = quotes
    end

    def calculate_rates
      result = []
      @insurer = Coverage::Rules.parse_file ## which will give {
                                        #"insurer_rates": {
                                       #"person_a": "windows+tables",
                                       # "person_b": "lights+tables",
                                       #"person_c": "doors+curtains"
                                      # }}
      @insurer[:insurer_rates].each do |k, v|
        @match_covers = match_cover(v.split("+"))
        result << [k, calculate_rate ]
      end
    end

    def match_cover(covers)
      covers = covers.map { |x| x.to_sym }
      @quotes.select { |k,v| covers.include?(k) }
    end

    def calculate_rate
      premium    = 0.0
      persentage = get_percentage_by_match_covers
      @match_covers.values.each do |v|
        premium += v * persentage
      end
      premium == 0 ? nil : premium
    end

    def get_percentage_by_match_covers
      if @match_covers.size == 2
        0.1
      elsif @match_covers.size == 1
        only_1_match_covers
      else
        0
      end
    end

    def only_1_match_covers
      index = position_of_customer_request
      case index
      when 0
        0.2
      when 1
        0.25
      when 2
        0.3
      else
        raise StandardError
      end
    end

    def position_of_customer_request
      (@quotes.to_a.reverse).index(@match_covers.to_a.flatten)
    end
  end
end


request = {:windows=>50, :contents=>30, :engine=>20}

Coverage::CalculateQuotes.new(request).calculate_rates
````
`````

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby Hash

Rather than using a verbose case statement:

> ```
>  case index
>       when 0
>         0.2
>       when 1
>         0.25
>       when 2
>         0.3
> ```

You could use a Hash:

```
rates = {0 => 0.2, 1 => 0.25, 2 => 0.3}
```

And the case can be replaced with:

```
rates[index]
```

---

### Rubocop Report

Use symbols as procs when possible.

> ```
> covers = covers.map { |x| x.to_sym }
> ```

This is a compact alternative:

```
covers = covers.map(&:to_sym)
```

---

Identify unused block arguments.

> ```
> @quotes.select { |k,v| covers.include?(k) }
> ```

Use an underscore to identify unused block arguments:

```
@quotes.select { |k, _v| covers.include?(k) }
```

---

Numeric predicates should use predicate methods instead of comparison operators if possible

> ```
> premium == 0 ? nil : premium
> ```

Use the predicate method *zero* instead:

```
premium.zero? ? nil : premium
```

Comment: Thanks rubocop changes I will do finally when my code gets finalize. I am looking strong ruby code review which will calculate the percentage in a different way and some refactor to my class definition